# For $R = \dfrac{\mathbb{Z}_2[A,B,T]}{\langle A^3 - B^3, T^3 - AB^2 - B^3 \rangle}$, is $t^n \in \langle a^n \rangle$ for any $n \geq 1$?

Tags: polynomials, commutative-algebra

Let $R = \dfrac{\mathbb{Z}_2[A,B,T]}{\langle A^3 - B^3, T^3 - AB^2 - B^3 \rangle}$ where $A,B,$ and $T$ are indeterminates. Let $a, b,$ and $t$ refer respectively to the residue classes of $A, B,$ and $T$ in $R$. I am trying to prove that $t^n \not\in \langle a^n \rangle$ for all $n \geq 1$.

I have checked $n = 3$ and $n = 60$ on Macaulay2. Actually, since $\langle a^n \rangle$ is principal, I think this should be an easy exercise--it comes down to verifying that $t^n \neq a^n$ and $t^n \neq 0$ (since we're over the field $\mathbb{Z}_2$ and $R$ is homogeneous if $A, B,$ and $T$ are given the degree $1$). However, I don't know how to approach a problem like this, and I would appreciate some guidance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$t^n=0$ is equivalent to $T^n\in{\langle A^3 - B^3, T^3 - AB^2 - B^3 \rangle}$. If this holds, then we can write $$T^n= (A^3 - B^3)u(A,B,T)+(T^3 - AB^2 - B^3)v(A,B,T).$$ Now send $B$ to $aA$, where $a^2+a+1=0$. (In fact, $\mathbb F_4=\mathbb F_2(a)$.) Then $T^n=(T^3+aA^3)v(A,aA,T)$, which is impossible. ($T$
is prime and coprime with $T^3+aA^3$. From $T^n=(T^3+aA^3)v(A,aA,T)$ we get $T^n\mid v(A,aA,T)$, so $1=(T^3+aA^3)v_1(A,aA,T)$, which is clearly impossible.)

Showing that $T^n-A^n\notin\langle A^3 - B^3, T^3 - AB^2 - B^3 \rangle$ is very easy: suppose the contrary and send $B$ to $A$. It follows that $T^n-A^n\in\langle T^3\rangle$, a contradiction.

Comment: This technique is new to me, and I am still trying to understand. When you send $B \rightarrow A$, that means you have tacitly passed to the quotient ring $\dfrac{\mathbb{Z}_2[A,B,T]}{\langle A - B \rangle}$, right? In that case, I can see how $T^n - A^n  \in \langle T^3, A - B \rangle$. How do I prove the stronger statement $T^n - A^n  \in \langle T^3 \rangle $?

Comment: No. When I said that $B$ is sent to $A$ I mean that I am using a ring homomorphism which does this, and the effect is to replace $B$ by $A$ in a polynomial relation. For instance, we assume that $T^n-A^n$ can be written as $(A^3-B^3)u(A,B,T)+(T^3-AB^2-B^3)v(A,B,T)$. When replace $B$ by $A$ the first term becomes zero and the second $T^3v(A,A,T)$.